# Where is Vue.use(VueResource) string in Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-resource

In many tutorials about VueJS I see this example:

```
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource);
```

But in newly created Laravel 5.3 project I found only this code (bootstrap.js file):

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource')
```

And found no "use" directive for vue-resource, but AJAX queries like this.$http.get() still work well. So, how Vue instance can use vue-resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vue-router` doesn't require `use` if `Vue` is declared globally. From the official docs:

> Some plugins provided by Vue.js official plugins such as vue-router automatically calls Vue.use() if Vue is available as a global variable. However in a module environment such as CommonJS, you always need to call Vue.use() explicitly.

In laravel, you will see that `Vue` is declared globally by attaching it to `window` like so:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
```

So the `use` is not required.

source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Using-a-Plugin

Comment: If I understand the concept behind Vue framework clearly... When I don't know if it is official plugin or not - I still can use Vue.use('some_plugin') and Vue will automatically prevents me from using the same plugin more than once, right?